# How to send @ character to Kannel using HTTP Client?

Tags: httpclient, kannel

I'm trying to send a SMS to the Kannel using HTTP Client through Get Method :
  - I don't want to encode it; as the @ character does not get sent correctly.

If I sent without encoding, I get error for the space character.
   The code is as follows :

```
  StringBuffer directives=new StringBuffer();
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  directives.append("username=" + username); 
  directives.append("&password=" + password);
  directives.append("&from=" + from);
  directives.append("&to=" + to);
  directives.append("&coding=0");
  // Without Encoding
  directives.append("&text=" + text);
  directives.append("&smsc=" + smsc);
  directives.append("&dlr-mask=" + dlrmask);
  directives.append("&dlr-url=" + dlrurl);
  URI uri = URIUtils.createURI("http", host, Integer.parseInt(port), "/cgi-bin/sendsms", directives.toString(), null);
  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
  HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpget);
```

I tried sending it using the POST method, where I set the content type = text/plain :
  - The kannel was not accepting the parameters

Following is the code:

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://" + host + ":" + port + "/cgi-bin/sendsms"); 
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from", from));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to",to));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text",text));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("smsc", smsc));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dlr-mask",dlrmask));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dlr-url",dlrurl));
 post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
```

So what is the best way to send sms to kannel?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to add "charset=..." parameter with charset of string you send via HTTP? For example "&charset=utf-8".

Comment: I have tried with "&charset=utf-8". Its not working. it gives error for the space character.

Comment: "text" parameter must be URL-encoded and spaces should be represented as "+" or "%20".

Comment: If space is represented with '+'. Then when we try to send '+' as part of message , it gets sent as space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure kannel to work with `post`

User Group

```
 group = sms-service
```

Replace  `get-url` with `post-url`

You also need the following  parameters that works with ONLY Post

```
send-sender
strip-keyword
```

On your application you need to also had some custom headers to use `Kannel POST`

This headers may include

```
X-Kannel-From   Only sent if send-sender is true
X-Kannel-To  
X-Kannel-Time    
X-Kannel-UDH    in hex format: 06050415820000
X-Kannel-SMSC    
X-Kannel-MClass  
X-Kannel-PID     
X-Kannel-Alt-DCS     
X-Kannel-MWI     
X-Kannel-Coding 0=7 Bits, 1=8 Bits, 2=UCS-2
X-Kannel-Compress    
X-Kannel-Validity    
X-Kannel-Deferred    
X-Kannel-Service
```

Please see documentation http://www.kannel.org/download/1.4.3/userguide-1.4.3/userguide.html on `Kannel Post` to understand the way it works